# Kafka Streams processing speed slows when empty processor is added

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Consider this Kafka Streams driver

```
public class TestDriver {

    private static final String SOURCE = "SOURCE";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ProtoDeserializer<Message> protoDeserializer = new ProtoDeserializer<>(Message.parser());
        ProtoSerializer<Message> protoSerializer = new ProtoSerializer<>();

        StringDeserializer stringDerializer = new StringDeserializer();
        StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

        Topology topologyBuilder = new Topology();
        topologyBuilder.addSource(SOURCE, stringDerializer, protoDeserializer, "input-messages")

            .addProcessor(DummyProcessor.NAME, DummyProcessor::new, SOURCE)

            .addSink("MAIN", "output-messages", stringSerializer, protoSerializer, DummyProcessor.NAME)
        ;

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topologyBuilder, getConfig());
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();

        System.out.println(streams.toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));

    }

    private static Properties getConfig() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test.stream-processor");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test.stream-processor");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker-1:9092,broker-2:9092,broker-3:9092");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 3);
        config.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 10);
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class);
        return config;
    }
}
```

The question is that when no processor is added to the topology (no `.addProcessor()` is included), the processing speed from source to sink is fine (means that I currently produce 25k messages/s and it has no problem to catch up).

However, when `DummyProcessor` is added, it suddenly processes 3k messages/s max (600k bytes).

DummyProcessor does basically nothing:

```
public class DummyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, Message> {

    public static final String NAME = "DUMMY_PROCESSOR";

    public void process(String key, Message originalMessage) {
        context().forward(key, originalMessage);
        context().commit();
    }
}
```

Is adding single "empty" processor such overhead for Streams performance? What is the cause of it? Is Kafka Streams so smart that when there's not processor it doesn't perform protobuf serde and only forwards data received? Anyway to speed it up?

*With such speed I'd need like x thousands more cpu threads available to be able to process all my data as 25k messages/s is 1 % of what I have. That sounds a lot.*

Comment: Does performance increase if you remove `context().commit();`?

Comment: @wardziniak yes, significantly 330k messages/s. I though the commit() is necessary though for streams to work (?). However, it seems it's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is caused because of requesting *commit* to often.

You don't need to call `ProcessorContext:commit()` at all.
Kafka Streams based on `commit.interval.ms` property performs commit (be default: `30000 ms`). If exactly once semantic is set its different value. You can details in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#streamsconfigs.

If in some use case you need commit more frequently you can call `ProcessorContext:commit()`. But you have to remember, that commit is not made Immediately (directly). It sets only flag to commit as soon it will be possible.

Comment: Ah, that did not come to my mind at all. Now it's crystal clear. Probably what confused me the most that pretty much all tutorials/videos/blog posts/other examples call `commit()` everytime everywhere so I asumed it's necessary. Thanks!